# Seeding Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to find a  clear example on how to seed associations between my models. I've been using Populator and Faker to batch create dummy date but when it comes to various associations I can't really find any examples that don't involve creating them manually.

For example I have two models, Facility and Venue.
Facility belongs to Venue and Venue has many facilities

I tried this according to populate ReadMe:

```
  Venue.delete_all
  Facility.delete_all   'Side note: Can I combine these somehow?'

  Venue.populate 20 do |venue|
    venue.name = Faker::Name.title
    venue.description = Faker::Lorem.paragraph(12)
    Facility.populate 3..8 do |facility|
      facility.venue_id = venue.id
      facility.name = Faker::Name.title,
      facility.description = Faker::Lorem.sentence
    end
  end
```

What this does is for every venue, it will create 3 to 8 Facilities...which sounds great and in the database the venue_id get's assigned properly. But in console, when I do `Facility.first.venue` I get an empty array. If I do `Facility.first.venue_id` I'll get an ID  but they're not 'truely' associated from what I can tell.

What's the correct way to do this please?

Comment: Set the `venue` then: `facility.venue = venue`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Populator directly touches the database and doesn't go through the model. So in the database table `Facilities` there isn't a column called `venue` so it fails.

Comment: If the `..._id` is populated, you're set. There's nothing more to it. However, you shouldn't be getting an array for `belongs_to`. How are your associations set up? UPD: scratch that, noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
20.times do
  name = Faker::Name.title
  description = Faker::Lorem.paragraph(12)
  venue = Venue.create!(name: name, description: description)
  rand(3..8).times do
    name = Faker::Name.title
    description = Faker::Lorem.sentence
    facility = Facility.new(name: name, description: description)
    facility.venue = venue
    facility.save!
  end
end
```

Also, to answer your side note question, `dependent: :destroy` allows you to delete all the children when the parent is destroyed:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facilities, dependent: :destroy
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Comment: Just wondering if there's a reason we use `Venue.create!` but `facility.new` then `facility.save`?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to assign ids of created objects to the one that has many of them.

Using `has_many :facilities, dependent: destroy` on the **Venue** model will be enough to destroy all of them when a **Venue** is gone:

```
Venue.destroy_all
20.times do |t|
  v = Venue.new(name: "title_#{t}", description: "a descr #{t}")
  v.facility_ids = rand(3..8).times do |t|
    Facility.create!(name: "name_#{t}", description: "sentence_#{t}").try(:id)
  end.compact
  v.save
end
```

In the past i used a nice gem from the Viget team: [Sprig](http://viget.com/extend/smarter-rails-seeding-with-sprig)

It lets you specify your seeds using **yml**. If you do a lot of seeding give it a shot.

Comment: I felt like that's what I had done originally with this line `facility.venue_id = venue.id` but that didn't work. You're method is a little different though since I was using Populator gem.

Comment: Basically my idea is to create a bunch of faclities, retrieve an array of their ids and bulk assign them to a venue.